# Two strings with (almost) the same value return 0 or 1 when compared for equality(they differ by a '\0' char)

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

In the following code:

```
string x="test";
string y="test";
y += '\0';
cout << (x==y) << endl;
```

prints:

> 0

But, the same code with a slight change:

```
string x="test";
string y="test";
y += "\0";
cout << (x==y) << endl;
```

prints:

> 1

The questions are:

1. Why is that so?
2. How is `operator==` implemented? Does it check every single char, or does it ignore `'\0'`?
3. I've read that C++ strings are not null-terminated. In a check I did about the existence of the `'\0'` char in a normal string literal, I got `1`. Is this undefined behavior?

Comment: Just read the source code and/or the spec (e.g. cppreference.com). BTW: That also explains the "not null-terminated". However, read that carefully, because "not null-terminated" means that null is a regular, non-terminating element value.

Comment: `"\0"` is a C-style string of zero length and gets converted to an empty `std::string`.

Comment: `"\0"` -- The `+` sees that this is a C-string literal and will thus search for the first null byte for termination.  Guess where the first null byte is?

Comment: You might also compare `"he\0ho"s` (literals string suffix) to `std::string("he\0ho")`. the latter `std:string` doesn't contain `o`.

Answer (score 1):

`'\0'` is a single `char` with an ordinal value of 0.  `operator+=(char)` adds *any* `char` to the string without regard to its value. Comparing `y.size()` before and after the append , you will see that the size increases by 1.

`"\0"` is a string literal, a `const char[2]` containing *two* null characters, one explicit by you and one implicit by the compiler. When treated as a C-style null-terminated string by `operator+=(const char*)`, its logical length stops at the first null character, thus its length is effectively 0.  Comparing `y.size()` before and after the append, you will see that the size does not change.

`operator==` takes `size()` into account. Two strings of different sizes will return false. Two strings of same size will compare all of their `char`s, including embedded null characters.